# C# can't connect to Docker Oracle database 19c w/ Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client

Tags: c#, oracle, docker

I have a C# application trying to connect to a local Docker container that is running the doctorkirk/oracle19c image, I can connect to the container with Oracle SQL Developer just fine, but I can't connect to it with my C# application.

This is the example code

```cs
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
...
...
string connStr = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=mydb)));User ID=user1;Password=pass1;"

using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(connStr))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("success");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

The only response I get is

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005):
> Connection request timed out

I have tried virtually every different way to write the connection string, if I omit the host from the connection string it still errors to the timeout error, i tried the max pool size, timeout amount, this doesn't change the error, but again I can connect just fine with the Oracle SQL Developer tool, and this is all running locally

Thanks

tried almost everything, at this point would just like a different error message

Comment: Since the Docker creator seems kind of old-school, maybe the service isn't setup properly and the SID works better. Try connecting with `(SID=mydb)` instead of `(SERVICE_NAME=mydb)`.

Comment: thanks, but yea I tried that as well, I'm completely stumped